# Couldn't start client Common Lisp Language Server

Tags: vscode, macos, lisp

## Couldn't start client Common Lisp Language Server

No se por que estoy teniendo este problema , viene originado de un plugin de vscode que descargue para [lisp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ailisp.commonlisp-vscode).

Una de las dependencias que el plugin necesita es  `ailisp/cl-lsp` el cual rosswell compila y el binario se localiza en `/Users/<name>/.roswell/bin/cl-lsp` y al ejecutarlo estoy teniendo este problema:

```lisp
;
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;
;     Symbol "LAYOUT-INFO" not found in the SB-KERNEL package.
;
;       Line: 765, Column: 43, File-Position: 28261
;
;       Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /Users/ranon-rat/.roswell/local-projects/ailisp/prepl/inspect.lisp" {1002D4C373}>
Unhandled UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                                          {1001548343}>:
  COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "prepl" "inspect">
```

Despues investigue y al parecer el problema se originaba en otro archivo, para ser mas especifico este`/Users/<name>/.roswell/local-projects/ailisp/prepl/inspect.lisp`
el cual cuando lo ejecuto igualmente estoy teniendo este otro problema

```lisp
Unhandled PACKAGE-DOES-NOT-EXIST in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                              {1001538143}>:
  The name "PREPL" does not designate any package.
```

pero es raro eso por que `prepl.asd` esta definido , y la estructura de los  archivos en ese directorio es algo como esto:

```lisp
├── README
├── commands.lisp
├── debug.lisp
├── inspect.lisp
├── package.lisp
├── prepl.asd
├── prepl.lisp
└── tests.lisp
```

Y el source del archivo que mencione es este

```lisp
;;;; Inspector for prepl

(in-package :prepl)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defconstant +default-inspect-length+ 20))

(defstruct (%inspect (:constructor make-inspect)
                     (:conc-name inspect-))
  ;; stack of parents of inspected object
  object-stack
  ;;  a stack of indices of parent object components
  select-stack)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: oh perdon en un momento lo soluciono

Comment: No se mucho sobre lisp y tampoco quiero usar algo como emacs o eso ya que me ha sido algo dificil configurarlo para que quede igual que portacle y aun no lo he logrado

Answer (score 0):

[Hay problemas](https://github.com/ailisp/commonlisp-vscode/issues/15) con las versiones nuevas de SBCL que dejaron de incluir LAYOUT-INFO

Se puede hacer un downgrade de la versión de sbcl usada por ros:

```
ros install sbcl/2.1.1
ros install sbcl-bin/2.1.1
ros use sbcl/2.1.1
ros use sbcl-bin/2.1.1
```

Después de esto las dependencias de commonlisp-vscode deberian insalar sin problema:

```
ros install ailisp/linedit
ros install ailisp/prepl
ros install ailisp/cl-lsp
```